# when does useEffect fire in componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I read below statement in a blog, it says something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  API.getUser(userId);
}, [userId]);
```

> Optionally the second parameter can also just be an empty array, in
>   this case it will only execute on `componentDidMount` and
>   `componentWillUnmount` and the effect won't run on `componentDidUpdate`.

Does the `API.getUser` got executed when the component got unmounted (`componentWillUnmount`)? as I know `componentWillUnmount` trigger when you go from page A to page B. I'm confused now, for me, above code act like `componentDidMount`, because `userId` will change from `undefined` to `id` once.

Comment: It's a long read but it's as it says the complete guide to `useEffect` by the creator: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a little confused with the wording, Its not the effect that is executed on unmount when you pass an empty array but the cleanup function which is the function returned from within the useEffect which will be executed.

for instance you can have the above effect like

```
useEffect(() => {
  API.getUser(userId);
  return () => {
      // cancel api here
  }
}, [userId]);
```

So in the above example, the anonymous function which is returned by useEffect will be called before the effect is run for the second time(which happens when userId changes) or at the time of unmount

Comment: ya the wording is confusing because it doesn't have the second return function

Answer (score 1):

You can return clean up function from useEffect which will run before unMount

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = props.source.subscribe(); // this will fire at after did Mount/ didUpdate
  return () => {
    // Clean up the subscription
    subscription.unsubscribe(); // this will afire at willUnmount
  };
});
```

If you pass empty array as second parameter.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = props.source.subscribe(); // this run only after first rnede i.e componentDidmount
  return () => {
    // Clean up the subscription
    subscription.unsubscribe(); // this will afire at willUnmount ie componentWillUnmount
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: no. its true. if you pass empty array as second parameter useEffect will run only after first render, it won't run after each update. and retunred function will run before unmount.

Comment: your first block of code has comment //// this will afire at willUnmount what do you mean?

Comment: empty array makes useEffect just like what @eramit2010 said. for Hanz code, every time the `useId` changed, the code inside useEffect will run

Comment: second parameter in useEffect is depedencies. so if you pass it as empty array it tells useEffect to run only after first render(componentDidUpdate) and returned function is clean up function so it will run before unmount(componentWillUnmount)

Comment: to avoid confusion: for first code sample `subscription.unsubscribe()` will be run at `cWU` but as well it will be run before each re-render as well.

Comment: no. useEffect never run before render. it always run after render. and clean up function runs only before unmount(componetWillUnmount).